# Unable resolve dependencies of custom annotation processor. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I have attempted to implement my own annotation processor and it looks like this:

MyProcessor.java:

```
package com.example.processing;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"com.example.annotations.Service", "com.example.annotations.Module"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    //...        

    return true;

}
```

Below is it's pom:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>crawler</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

In a separate application I have annotated some classes using the custom annotations *com.example.annotations.Service* and *com.example.annotations.Module* defined in the processing application. The processing application is added as a dependecy in the other application. See below:

pom.xml (In the annotated application)

```
...

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>crawler</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependecy>
    ...
</dependencies>

...
```

However when I attempt an *mvn clean install* on the annotated application (after doing *mvn install* on the processing application) I end up with the following error:

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.example.processing.MyProcessor could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Predicate
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException:     Compilation failure
error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.example.processing.MyProcessor could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Predicate
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
```

What is the problem here. Do I need to build my processing application jar so that it contains all dependencies? From what I have researched I should't have to.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.